# how to get the urn of the bucket file

Tags: autodesk-forge

Please tell me how to get the urn of the bucket file.
You can get the urn that is included in the response when uploading to the bucket, but I'd like to obtain the urn of the file already uploaded to the bucket.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [GET /buckets/:bucketKey/objects](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/) endpoint to get a list of all files in your bucket. In the response, each file will have its `objectId` (for example, `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/myfile`). Take the `objectId` and encode it in base64, for example, using https://www.base64encode.org. The encoded string is your URN.