# Translate revit model to svf from bucket id

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Im trying to translate a revit model to svf using this endpoint `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job`

According to the docs this endpoint needs at lest these two attributes to work:

- urn
- formats

First I got the objectId from the desired object inside my bucket :

```
"objectId":"urn:adsk.objects:os.object:gkwz1o52jxgqnqkhay5dlgcg7e2xglal_tutorial_bucket/rst_basic_sample_project.rvt"
```

and then I used https://www.base64encode.org/ to encode this string and get my urn, following the advice from this question [how to get the urn of the bucket file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267698/how-to-get-the-urn-of-the-bucket-file). The result urn was this:

```
dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2t3ejFvNTJqeGdxbnFraGF5NWRsZ2NnN2UyeGdsYWxfdHV0b3JpYWxfYnVja2V0L3JzdF9iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ=
```

Finally I got the format from the examples and I removed the `=` from the urn string.

My final body data is this:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2t3ejFvNTJqeGdxbnFraGF5NWRsZ2NnN2UyeGdsYWxfdHV0b3JpYWxfYnVja2V0L3JzdF9iYXNpY19zYW1wbGVfcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ"
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf",
                "views": ["2d", "3d"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But im getting this message:

[image]

I thought that was I getting the right object, and getting the urn, but still don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide more information about how exactly you're making the HTTP request to Forge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint URL, payload, and the base64-encoded object ID all seem to be fine. Try a couple of things:

- Make sure that you that you're using `POST` method when calling the endpoint
- Make sure that you're using the same Forge credentials (client ID and secret) you used when uploading the Revit model to the bucket
- Try other ways of calling the endpoint, for example, using [Postman](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/my-postman-collection) or the [VSCode extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thank you. My error was in the method. But when reading the developer message I thought it was refering to the objectId that was not found in the bucket, but I guess it was refering to the endpoint resource.

Comment: Yes the messaging is a bit confusing. I guess it's because in the REST terminology, _endpoints_ represent _resources_.